# Data Frame creating column from existing column only takes into account the first row

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
head(test)
                     sku               array                 
1 AQ665ELABLKLANID-81796       0,0,0,1,1,1,2            
2 AQ665ELABLKMANID-81797   2,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1              
3 AQ665ELABLKNANID-81798     0,1,2,1,1,0,4,1           
4 AQ665ELABLKOANID-81799             0,1,0,1            
5 AQ665ELABLKPANID-81800     1,4,4,2,3,7,2,2             
6 AQ665ELABLKRANID-81802             0,1,1,0
```

And I would like to add a column named first that contains for each row the first element of array:

```
test$first = strsplit(test$array,",")[[1]][1]
```

But what I get is the following :

```
head(test)
                     sku               array   first             
1 AQ665ELABLKLANID-81796       0,0,0,1,1,1,2   0            
2 AQ665ELABLKMANID-81797   2,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1   0              
3 AQ665ELABLKNANID-81798     0,1,2,1,1,0,4,1   0           
4 AQ665ELABLKOANID-81799             0,1,0,1   0            
5 AQ665ELABLKPANID-81800     1,4,4,2,3,7,2,2   0             
6 AQ665ELABLKRANID-81802             0,1,1,0   0
```

I dont understand why all the rows get the value only from the array of the first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you actually want:

```
test$first <- sapply(strsplit(test$array,","),"[",1)
test

#                     sku             array first
#1 AQ665ELABLKLANID-81796     0,0,0,1,1,1,2     0
#2 AQ665ELABLKMANID-81797 2,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1     2
#3 AQ665ELABLKNANID-81798   0,1,2,1,1,0,4,1     0
#4 AQ665ELABLKOANID-81799           0,1,0,1     0
#5 AQ665ELABLKPANID-81800   1,4,4,2,3,7,2,2     1
#6 AQ665ELABLKRANID-81802           0,1,1,0     0
```

In your attempt,

```
strsplit(test$array,",")[[1]]
```

gives you the split-apart version of `test$array[1]`, from which you then subset the first element, which happens to be `0`. Hence, all your values end up being `0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you just please explain me what is the purpose of "[" ?

Comment: "[" is an extraction function, the same as doing x[1]. See ?Extract in the inline help.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose some regex could also be of use here. Something along the lines of the following might come in handy:

```
gsub("(^[0-9]+)(,.*)", "\\1", test$array)
# [1] "0" "2" "0" "0" "1" "0"
gsub("(^.*?),(.*)", "\\1", test$array, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "0" "2" "0" "0" "1" "0"
```

There are some packages (like "stringi" and "stringr") that make this kind of stuff easier to do.

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first_regex(test$array, pattern="[0-9]+")
# [1] "0" "2" "0" "0" "1" "0"
```

This also lets you easily extract the last value with:

```
stri_extract_last_regex(test$array, pattern="[0-9]+")
# [1] "2" "1" "1" "1" "2" "0"
```

Comment: Probably simpler in some ways. +1